# Open local file from Excel Cell in Android

Tags: file-system, hyperlinks, microsoft-excel

In Android, I wish to open a local file from a Hyperlink in Excel. XLSX file and the linked image are in the same directory folder. I've tried the following:

[image]

```
=HYPERLINK("cat.jpg", "Cat")

=HYPERLINK("./cat.jpg", "Cat")

=HYPERLINK(".\cat.jpg", "Cat")

=HYPERLINK("file://\storage\emulated\0\Download\Cat.jpg", "Cat")

=HYPERLINK("file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Cat.jpg", "Cat")

=HYPERLINK("/storage/emulated/0/Download/1.png", "Cat")

=HYPERLINK("file://storage\emulated\0\Download\Cat.jpg", "Cat")

=HYPERLINK("file://storage/emulated/0/Download/Cat.jpg", "Cat")

=HYPERLINK("storage/emulated/0/Download/1.png", "Cat")
```

I get the same error message on all Cells:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve the above result? If Android as an OS restricts launching another app programmatically, can we we have the open with dialogue similar to the one in ES Explorer.

[image]

If it affects - I downloaded MS Excel via Play Store and I'm not a Office 365 user.